# ag grid restrict column values

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using the community version of ag-grid. I am trying to replicate [this page](https://blog.ag-grid.com/add-new-rows-using-a-pinned-row-at-the-top-of-the-grid/) where a user enters a new row and in particular on the sports column where the values are restricted to a certain list, I don't care about the images. However I am able to enter any value into the sports column, not sure what I am missing?

```
let rowData = [];
let inputRow = {};

function setRowData(newData) {
  let currData = [];
  gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node => currData.push(node.data));

 currData.push(newData[0]);
 gridOptions.api.setRowData(currData);
}

function setInputRow(newData) {
 inputRow = newData;
 gridOptions.api.setPinnedTopRowData([inputRow]);
}


const columnDefs = [
  { field: 'athlete' },
  { field: 'age' },
  {
    field: 'sport',
    cellEditorParams: {
    values: ['Tennis', 'Swimming'],
    cellEditorPopup: true,
  },
 }
];

const startData = [
   {athlete: 'bob', sport: 'Swimming', age: '35'},
   {athlete: 'john', sport: 'Tennis', age: '36'},
]

const gridOptions = {
 rowData: startData,
 columnDefs: columnDefs,
 pinnedTopRowData: [inputRow],

defaultColDef: {
  flex: 1,
  editable: true,
  valueFormatter: (params) =>
    isEmptyPinnedCell(params)
      ? createPinnedCellPlaceholder(params)
      : undefined,
 },

getRowStyle: ({ node }) =>
   node.rowPinned ? { 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-style': 'italic' } : 0,

onCellEditingStopped: (params) => {
  if (isPinnedRowDataCompleted(params)) {
    // save data
    setRowData([...rowData, inputRow]);
    //reset pinned row
    setInputRow({});
   }
 },
};

function isEmptyPinnedCell({ node, value }) {
  return (
   (node.rowPinned === 'top' && value == null) ||
   (node.rowPinned === 'top' && value == '')
  );
}

function createPinnedCellPlaceholder({ colDef }) {
  return colDef.field[0].toUpperCase() + colDef.field.slice(1) + '...';
}

function isPinnedRowDataCompleted(params) {
  if (params.rowPinned !== 'top') return;
  return columnDefs.every((def) => inputRow[def.field]);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
   const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#mygrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed that exactly

```
cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
```

Change your sport column definition like below

```
{
  field: 'sport',
  cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: ['Tennis', 'Swimming'],
    cellEditorPopup: true,
  }
},
```

Here's my example as a reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pinned-input-row-blog-fzknf4?file=index.js

Comment: thanks for the above. It appears though the agRichSelectCellEditor is not available in the community version of ag grid & without that line it does not work